# Not able to separate each word that has an empty space and storing it in array for some text

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Sorry as the question is bit lengthy.

I have this string `"Hello how are you"`

When I pass it to this function in ASP.Net C#

```
private void separateSpaces(string text)
{
 string[] separatedWords = text.Split(' ');
 for(int i=0;i<separatedWords.length;i++)
 {
   Response.Write("<br>"+separatedWords[$i]);
 }
}
```

When I run that string to this function , I get my expected answer perfectly. Like

```
Hello
how
are
you
```

But when I subject this text. I am getting a wrong output

This is the text

```
Fusion Technologies, Hyderabad, India                           May 2005 – July 2007
Net Developer
```

Everything breaks fine , except for

```
India May
```

it is treated as a string together. I need both of them to be separate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `India May` is treated as single string because there's no space between them (and for example other whitespace, like `\t`)?

Try this and see whether it works:

```
string[] seperatedWords = text.Split(default(string[]), 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The `default(string[])` is simply `null`. When [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) receives `null` as first argument, it treats all whitespace characters (matched by [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx)) as delimeters.

Comment: Strange, I've copied text you've provided and there are no tab symbols

Answer (score 2):

```
string data = "Fusion Technologies, Hyderabad, India                 May 2005 ";
var items = data.Split(
                       new[] {' ', ',', '\t' }, 
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Output:

```
[0]: "Fusion"
[1]: "Technologies"
[2]: "Hyderabad"
[3]: "India"
[4]: "May"
[5]: "2005"
```

Comment: This doesn't solve his problem, as he said "India" and "May" were on the same line, and your solution doesn't really do anything to address that.

Comment: @Lester: could you please elaborate, sorry I didn get your point regarding "same line"

Comment: Ty sll. I tried yours first and i got the same output as mine and later i tried jimmy's and it worked as charm. I will have your answer as my 2nd backup. +1 to you.

Comment: The problem is that "India      May" is treated as a single word in the array. The spacing between "India" and "May" isn't an empty entry in the resulting array, so using your suggested overload wouldn't change anything.

Comment: I believe adding one more separator `'\t'` would solve the problem. Before posting answer I've copied sample text and checked code I've provided, so it works since only space symbols found between words, not sure why tabs are not there but I've added tab separator to keep solution more generic

Answer (score 0):

Although in your code sample the words are separated by spaces, the actual text probably has a tab character or other whitespace character separating the words. You'll want to do a

```
text = text.Replace("\t", " ");
```

or something similar before splitting the text.

Comment: Or even better, define `'\t'` as a separator as well: `data.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' })`